# What is the Cisco IOS 12 "Ctrl +C" Key sequence to Break an operation

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-12

I screwed up and didn't configure a router for "no ip domain lookup" and then inadvertently pasted a slew of commands into Hyperterminal and now my session is cycling through a gizillion domain lookups that will finish around Febtober the year 2033.

Already tried finding this answer here at Stack and got nothing and Google just gives me a worthless phone book of everything else but the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl + Shift + 6 ?

I believe this is it.

Edit:  Ron is correct, I do think you need to press X afterwards.

Comment: I think you need to type an "X" after.

Comment: Actually, I succeeding with just the Ctrl+Shift+6 and without the X, the prompt answer helped me ALOT and I'm grateful.

Comment: "x" is only required for outgoing connections from the Cisco node.

ctrl + shift + 6 then x basically puts the outgoing connection into suspend mode.

If you just want to break from CLI prompts ctrl + shift + 6 should be fine... but it also depends on your terminal client.